# Issue with validating Arm template using DeploymentsOperations.StartValidate

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am currently working on a project where i deploy multiple arm templates each deploying a VM and doing few operations on them. I wanted handle quota issues by calling template validation before triggerring the first deployment. So, i created a template which has logic to create required VMs and i am using this template only for validation (to check if quota will not be exceeded).

Since our code already has the ResourceManagementClient, i tried the following code:

```
Deployment parameters = new Deployment(
                new DeploymentProperties(DeploymentMode.Incremental)
                {
                    Template = templateFile,
                    Parameters = parameterFile,
                });

DeploymentsValidateOperation dp = deployments.StartValidate(groupName, "validation", parameters);
```

But when i try to access the Value from the variable dp, i keep getting the following exception:

> Generic Exception System.InvalidOperationException: The operation has
> not completed yet.    at Azure.Core.ArmOperationHelpers`1.get_Value()
> at
> Azure.ResourceManager.Resources.DeploymentsValidateOperation.get_Value()
> at DeployTemplate.Program.d__3.MoveNext() in
> \Program.cs:line 88

I even added a loop after the "StartValidate" to wait till the dp.HasCompleted is set to true. But this seems to run indefinetly. I also tried the "StartValidateAsync" method, which seems to have the same issue.
I wanted to understand if i am using this method correctly? if there is a better way to do the template validations? I could not find any examples on this method`s usage. if possible please share any code snippet where this method is used for my reference.

Note: Currently, Since this is not working, i am testing with Fluent Api way. That seems to be working. But, it requires lot of changes in our code as it creates ambiguity with many classes in "Azure.ResourceManager.Resources" which are already used for other operations.

Answer (score 0):

I found that even though the deployment operations `HasCompleted` field is not set, when I call `dp.GetRawResponse()`, it returns the exact errors expected.

I now use this to validate my templates.